# Is it possible to Add a revit file to a scene and publish it as WebScene using ArcGIS C# API?

Tags: c#, arcgis, arcgis-runtime-net

I would like to know if I could place a Revit File to a Scene and then publish the Scene as Web Scene to my profile using ArcGIS C# API / REST API.

I do not have ArcGIS Server installed. I have ArcGIS Web and ArcGIS Desktop.

My aim is to the published web scenes in my web application which I am able to when I publish the web scenes published using ArcGIS Pro.

I would like to publish web scenes to ArcGIS Web without using ArcGIS Pro. Also would have to Create Web Scenes using ArcGIS C# API/REST API and Add a 3D layer using the same. Then publish it to my ArcGIS Portal using the ArcGIS C#/REST API's.

I would also like to know the endpoints to which I should be uploading when I'm using REST API when I don't have ArcGIS Server installed in my server.